# Calling Restful WCF POST method with C#

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I call a WCF method with the type POST from a C# class?

WCF method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           UriTemplate = "/process",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
MyRespons Process(MyRequest req);
```

How can I call this from an aspx codebehind?

I've tried to receive the stream with webclient, it works with any get method, but not with POST. The method works in Fiddler and POSTER:

```
string getDeclarations = string.Format("{0}/process", ServiceBaseAddress);
var proxy = new WebClient();
proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += ProxyDownloadDeclarationsCompleted;
proxy.DownloadStringAsync((new Uri(getDeclarations)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery. And here is a [great example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call) for you to use as well.

This is an example code block.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: /* YOUR URL */,
    data: JSON.stringify(/* YOUR POST DATA */),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        /* SUCCESS FUNCTION */
    },
    error: function (error) {
        /* ERROR FUNCTION */
    }
});
```

## Edited

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117421/webclient-uploaddata-correct-usage-for-post-request) to a Stackoverflow example using `WebClient` to perform a `POST`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Is there a way to the same in C#, aspx codebehind?

Comment: @Gino: But you did ask for a way to do it in .aspx, not in .cs. Try to be more specific in the question instead of in the comments ;-)

Comment: @Thomas -  I started my question with: How can I call a WCF method with the type POST from a C# class? but I ended it with aspx page. It's correct now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add a Service reference to your WCF service in your project where you want to use the WCF service?
To do this, right click your project in the Solution explorer and select Add Service reference. Then type in your URL to your WCF service and you can use it as you referenced any other DLL or project with objects and methods.

Comment: Yes Tim, and that will solve the problem :). But is it possible to call that POST Method from a C# code behind by calling the link?

Comment: Take a look at HttpRequest and set the HttpMethod to 'Post'.

Comment: @Gino - I'm not sure you understand the technology fully so let me try and help. Tim has successfully answered your question. Add a service reference and then in the `Click` event of the link call the service to get a response. You don't **call the link**, does that make sense?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not sure what technology you mean. By adding a service reference I'll have full control over the WCF Service. My question is whay calling a POST method is not possible using WebClient.

Comment: I marked the answer of TimVK as correct as it answers my question as I stated it.

Comment: @Gino - it's not working for a post request because you're using the wrong method. That method is specifically for the `GET` verb. You need to use the `UploadValues` method for the `POST` verb. I'll modify my answer with a reference to another Stackoverflow example.