# Calling an ASP.Net RESTful POST controller API method with HTTPClient.PostAsync

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

A colleague has written an Azure Mobile Service API which includes the following controller method:

```csharp
public class SegmentationController : ApiController
{
    // [...]

    // POST api/<controller>/id
    public async Task<string> Post(string id)
    {
        // [...]
```

I am trying to call that from a Windows Universal app. The calls to GET methods work without issue but I am failing to call that POST method. Here is what I've tried:

```csharp
response = await client.PostAsync("api/segmentation/", new StringContent(item.Id));
    // 405 Method Not Allowed

response = await client.PostAsync("api/segmentation/" + item.Id, new StringContent(""));
    // 500 Internal Server Error

response = await client.PostAsync("api/segmentation/", new StringContent("id=" + item.Id));
    // 405 Method Not Allowed

response = await client.PostAsync("api/segmentation/", new StringContent("{\"id\":" + item.Id + "}"));
    // 405 Method Not Allowed
```

(N.B. `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` used in [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117700/575530) is not available on WinRT / Windows Universal.)

It is possible that my second call is correct and that the error is in the server side code; we are exploring that possibility.

What is the correct way to make a POST call to an ASP.Net RESTful API method which expects a parameter called "id" of type `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server error. Once we had added error reporting code we could see that the problem was the server failing to load a C++ DLL it relied on due to an x64 /x86 mismatch on Azure. The call style that now works is the second one I list in the question:

```csharp
response = await client.PostAsync("api/segmentation/" + item.Id, new StringContent(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is the problem. You have two options:

1. Use a query parameter instead of body. e.g. api/segmentation?id=abc
2. Add `[FromBody]` Attribute to your parameter. e.g. `public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]string id)`
   Now your parameter is read from body. by default only complex types are read from body.

For more details see [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)